# Is emptying Bluetooth share folder safe?

Tags: bluetooth

I need space, so I have emptied some cache and data from different sites.

What would I lose if I emptied my Bluetooth share?

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no problem in emptying the Bluetooth share folder. It doesn't contain any file that could make an application force close or any other trouble!

You do lose the files inside, though. Those might be files you wanted to keep.